# Can we show/hide different content in one div without using Select Method instead by just simple mouse click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to show/hide different content in one div without using Select Method instead by just simple mouse click on div?

**For Example:**

```css
.inv{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="inv">
 
  <div> Option 1 </div>
  <div> Option 2 </div>
  <div> Option 3 </div>
 
  <div class="inv">Content 1</div>
  <div class="inv">Content 2</div>
  <div class="inv">Content 3</div>

</div>
```

If I click on 'Option 1' div it show me the all content in 'Content 1'

**Option 1 -> Content 1**

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes its possible just use the display:"none" to do so with event handlers

Answer (score 2):

To do it *strictly without JavaScript*, you can use checkboxes with labels, although you would have to modify your markup:

```css
.inv {
  display: none;
}

label{
  display: block;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked + .inv{
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<label for="one"> Option 1 </label>
<label for="two"> Option 2 </label>
<label for="three"> Option 3 </label>

<input type="checkbox" id="one">
<div class="inv">Content 1</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="two">
<div class="inv">Content 2</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="three">
<div class="inv">Content 3</div>
```

If you don't want to change the current markup too much, you'll have to use JS. The following example uses [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to identify the elements to toggle.

```js
$('div[data-for]').click(function() {
  $(`.inv[data-id="${this.dataset.for}"]`).toggle()
})
```

```css
.inv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-for="one"> Option 1 </div>
<div data-for="two"> Option 2 </div>
<div data-for="three"> Option 3 </div>

<div class="inv" data-id="one">Content 1</div>
<div class="inv" data-id="two">Content 2</div>
<div class="inv" data-id="three">Content 3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried Html solution and It worked for me.